# MS Access 2007 doesn't allow to group form objects anymore like in 2003?

Tags: microsoft-access

It's a long time I haven't looked at MS Access but I clearly remembered it was possible to select multiple objects (lines, textbox, etc.) and type Ctrl + G to group them.

In Access 2007 I can't make it work and I can't find any context menu to do so.

Has this feature been erased by MS ?

Answer (score 1):

In MS Access 2010, highlight all the necessary objects.  Click on Arrange, then Size/Space and finally Group.

Answer (score 0):

I can guarantee that if there was a shortcut for grouping, Ctrl-G would not have been it, as that has always been the shortcut to the Debug/Immediate window (at least, since A2000). In A2003, there is no shortcut defined for this -- you had to do it through the menus (Format | Group).

In A2007, Grouping has been replaced with Layouts. If you search on "align controls" and then go to the first help topic ("Automatically align controls on a form"), and it will walk you through how it all works. It's substantially more versatile than the old group (it can be used to resize controls when the form resizes, for instance).

For finding features in A2007 when you're familiar with old versions of Access, you might find this [Flash-based UI translator](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access/HA102388991033.aspx) helpful. It's not perfect, as it can't translate what has been completely changed, but it can help a lot.

Comment: Grouping is not the same feature as aligning. So you mean they just erase this feature ?! Seems like a regression to me that is unacceptable. Maybe when Bill Gates has gone, Microsoft is going mad :)

Comment: I'm not an A2007 user, so I could be wrong. I couldn't see anything analogous to grouping except for layouts.

Answer (score 0):

Select Customise Quick Access Toolbar by right clicking on the ribbon.
Under 'Choose Commands From'
Select
'Form Design Tools | Arrange Tab'

There you will find the Group and Ungroup icons from older Access versions.
Add these to the toolbar so they are always available.